# Code contracts bug? Order of elements in expression in generic method and value types

Tags: c#, generics, code-contracts, value-type

Consider the following code, compiled with code contracts static analysis:

```cs
void TestGood<T>(T arg)
{
    Contract.Requires(arg != null);
}

void TestBad<T>(T arg)
{
    Contract.Requires(null != arg);
}

void RunTest()
{
    TestGood(Guid.Empty); // No warnings
    TestBad(Guid.Empty);  // Warning - "CodeContracts: requires unproven: null != arg"
}
```

Looks like the order of the parameters in the binary `==` expression is important, which doesn't make much sense.

It's not limited to the `Guid` type. For example, `struct MyStruct { }` gives the same behavior.

Strangely, if we pass a built in numeric type (e.g. the `int` value `0`), there is no warning.

So the questions are:

1. Is there any reason why the call to `TestBad` gives a warning?
2. If not, is this a bug in the code contracts static analyzer?

---

Using Code Contracts Version 1.5.60502.11 with Visual Studio 2012. Here's [a screenshot showing the settings used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY6W5.png). Also, as suggested I've asked the same question in the [code contracts user forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eb78d0db-3034-4e27-8ca2-9e516efd3568/requires-unproven-for-value-type-when-order-of-arguments-is-reversed-in-x-null-expression).

Comment: Looks like a bug, you should check with the Code Contracts team in their forum for that. That said, don't put null first in the equality check, it's rather unorthodox in C#.

Comment: What version of CC are you using? What options in static checker are turned on? I have "message : CodeContracts: Checked 2 assertions: 2 correct" as a result. CC version is 1.4.50327.0

Comment: Code "Contracts" Bug!  Ha!  Get it??  =)

Comment: @Dennis, I added the version & settings info at the end of the question

Comment: @sinelaw: updating to latest version reproduces the warning. +1 for bug.